# Logic Apps skip SQL new row trigger after I created SQL table

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have SQL item is created triggered and it worked fine for weeks. 
There is SQL table with Id column, which primary key

Now I have removed table in SQL and recreated with same name. There is new one new column.

I have updated "Compose" in Logic Apps to add new column in compose json. Obviously LogicApps finds table and columns.

My problem is now that Logic Apps does not get triggered anymore even new row is created. Why???

Comment: Just a guess, but if you deleted and recreated the table, you probably have to recreate the trigger. My instinct tells me that some unique table/event identifier was also deleted or changed.

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution provided below helps your problem, could you please mark it as "accepted", thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the new sql table can't trigger the logic although they have the same name just as Joel mentioned in the comment. Each sql table has its unique identity and when we create the trigger in logic app, the trigger will associates the table by the unique identity. So you need to re-create the trigger when you remove the table and re-create a table with same name.

But here provide a workaround which can help you simplify the steps, in this way we do not need to remove the trigger and create a new trigger in logic app. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** After you delete the original table and create a new one with same table name, you can go to your logic app trigger and choose the "Enter custom value".
[image]

**2.** Then type any letters for the "Table name" such as "test" and **click "Save" button**(click "Save" button" is necessary).
[image]

**3.** After that, choose your sql table in the trigger again and click "Save" button.
[image]

Now, the trigger will associates to the new sql table. It will be triggered when an item is created in your sql table.

Hope it helps~